# Custom resources in Environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'd like to track the Docker Swarm stack deployments in the [Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops).  I don't use K8S and I'm deploying to a Docker swarm rather than a single virtual machine.

Is it possible to set that up using the

```
jobs:
  - deployment: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Pipelines, only the [Kubernetes resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-kubernetes?view=azure-devops) and [virtual machine resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops) types are currently supported.

> While an environment is a grouping of resources, the resources themselves represent actual deployment targets. The [Kubernetes resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-kubernetes?view=azure-devops) and [virtual machine resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops) types are currently supported.

Other resource types are not supported.